# Hibernate Mapping Exception Could not determine type for: java.nio.file.Path

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an entity Photo as below

```
@Entity
class Photo {

Path imagePath;

public Path getImagePath(){
return imagePath;
// setter
}
```

In this entity i have to nio.Path how can i solve thiss problem or make the table in db to accept strings as path 
the error stack is below

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.nio.file.Path, at table: photo, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(image_path)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:431)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use an `AttributeConverter`.

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

@Converter // may want to set autoApply to true
public class PathConverter implements AttributeConverter<Path, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Path attribute) {
        return attribute == null ? null : attribute.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Path convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        return dbData == null ? null : Paths.get(dbData);
    }

}
```

This converter example will only store the path part of the `Path`. It won't maintain any other information such as what `FileSystem` it belongs to (and will assume the default `FileSystem` when converting from `String` to `Path`).

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import javax.persistence.Convert;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class Photo {

    @Convert(converter = PathConverter.class) // needed if autoApply isn't true
    private Path imagePath;

}
```

See the documentation of the following for more information:

- [`AttributeConverter`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/AttributeConverter.html)
- [`Converter`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/Converter.html)
- [`Convert`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/Convert.html)

Answer (score 0):

Path is not an Entity, so if you want the db to store it as String, you will have to change the type to String and use the following Paths.get(String path) to return the Path

```
@Entity
class Photo {

     String imagePathStr;

public String getImagePathStr(){
     return imagePath;
// setter
}

@Transient
public Path getImagePath(){
     return Paths.get(imagePathStr);
}
```

Comment: so we should two getImagePath ?you answer is not clear can you re write the whole so i get what u mean ?

Comment: getImagePathStr() allows you to retrieve the string path from the database while getImagePath is a transient method to convert the string path into a Path object.